# Is my file saving logic correct?

Tags: java, file

My java app calls a rest endpoint and in the response body is a 10GB XML file. Before I send the rest quest, I ask the service how many records will be in the file. I then retrieve the file. When I run my app, the file is saved successfully but only roughly 50% of the expected records. There are 2 reasons the file doesn't have all the records:

1. The file sent from the rest endpoint only has 50% of the expected records
2. My app is falling over when before it has finished downloading

My question is, if in scenario 2 and my app falls over, would I see an exception stating so? I do not see an exception, in fact, I see my log statement after the save is saved saying 'File successfully saved'.

EDIT: I have downloaded the file outside of my app, via a curl request and the same thing happened - only 50% of the expected population was downloaded. This proves the issue isn't with my file-saving logic.

```
public void saveFile() {
    try {
        downloadAndSaveFile();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("A error has occurred processing all content, caused by {}", e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private void downloadAndSaveFile() throws Exception {
    long recordCount = countRecords();
    LOGGER.info("Number of records to process is {}", recordCount);

    if (recordCount > 0 ) {
        InputStream dataToSave = getAllContent();
        saveStream(dataToSave);
        LOGGER.info("File successfully saved.");
    } else {
        LOGGER.error("No content to retrieve");
        throw new RuntimeException("There are no records to process");
    }
}


public InputStream getAllContent() throws Exception {
    return callRestEndpoint(webTarget).readEntity(InputStream.class);
}

private Response callRestEndpoint(WebTarget target) throws InterruptedException {
    Response response = null;

    for (int numberOfTries = 0; numberOfTries < reconnectRetries; numberOfTries++) {
        try {
            response = makeGetRequest(target);

            if (OK.getStatusCode() == response.getStatus()) {
                break;
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            retryRequest(numberOfTries, ex);
        }
    }

    return response;
}

public void saveStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    File fileToCreate = new File(fileName);

    if (!fileToCreate.exists()) {
        fileToCreate.mkdirs();
    }

    Files.copy(
            inputStream,
            fileToCreate.toPath(),
            StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING
    );

    closeQuietly(inputStream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is my file saving logic correct?

No.

```
if (!fileToCreate.exists()) {
    fileToCreate.mkdirs();
}
```

Here you are creating every element in `fileToCreate` as a directory, including the final element. So trying to open it later as a file will fail. And the `exists()` test is pointless. It should be:

```
fileToCreate.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

> if in scenario 2 and my app falls over, would I see an exception stating so

Yes, provided you print or log it somewhere. The method will definitely throw one.

Comment: in that case, you're saying it's an issue in the rest endpoint because my file saves and I see no exceptions printed to the logs, just the 'file saved successfully' message.